# How to backup Console logs?

Tags: macos, file, logs, console

I'd like to make backup of some specific console logs.

How do I find the location of a specific Console log file on my Mac to copy as back up?

Comment: Buddy, we're not in your head, if you want us to provide you some help, help us with a better description of the issue ;)

Comment: While in the Console app window, click on any of logs that interest you (on the left side), then either right click and use "Reveal in Finder", or use shortcut cmd-r.

Comment: would like to know is not from Console. The content is different from what I asked. Somebody changed the title and contents.

Answer (score 1):

Console.app's logs are stored in the following locations:

```
/var/log
/Library/Logs
~/Library/Logs
```

To back up all the logs, simply copy the contents of these three folders to another location.

To back up a single log, look in Console.app for the log that you want to back up, select it in the sidebar, then press ⌘R (or right-click and select Reveal in Finder). This file can then be copied to another location.

Comment: Note that many apps use the Apple logging that puts all the logs into a database not a flat file

Comment: @Mark so where is that database located, and is it accessible?

Comment: /var/log/asl /var/log/DiagnosticMessages + others - basically a non text format

Comment: @Mark Ah, ok; still under /var/log so could be backed up without any extra user intervention.

Comment: See man ask for the api - and you can (but should not) put them anywhere - as can syslog including on another machine - I think the question needs to explain what he wants in more detail

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is simple.

While you are looking at magnitude of console logs pick the one you want.

While in the Console app window, click on any of logs that interest you (on the left side), then either right click and use "Reveal in Finder", or use shortcut <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>. –  Buscar웃 5 hours ago